# Does Eli have access to the Daniel Jackson videos?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

In the first episode of Stargate Universe it is revealed that Daniel Jackson recorded a series videos for (Eli/Anyone new to the Stargate Program) to explain various concepts.

Eli is also creating a type of home movie, on his laptop, of the various exploits that the Destiny's crew get up to on their journey. Is it known if the video series Daniel created made it to Destiny?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### At least one of the videos made it onto Destiny.

In [Incursion, Part I](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Incursion,_Part_1) we see Eli watching Daniel's "Lucian Alliance" training video.

> INT—KINO ROOM
>
> [Eli watches a **Daniel Jackson orientation video** on his iPhone.]
>
> **DANIEL:** (over video) *The Lucian Alliance is an organization of humans from a number of sovereign planets who have taken control of the resources and technology…*
>
> <sub><sup>[Incursion, Part I - Original Screenplay](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/SGU_1.19_%22Incursion_Part_1%22_Transcript#Transcript)</sup></sub>

Comment: Great find. You have my +1